# Check if there is a Object matching another one from a Collection in Symfony2; Notifications

Tags: symfony, notifications

I'd like to get some help with my project.

I'm having a list of games (matches) that require every user participating to take some action (approve the score, accept an invite etc.)

What I'd like to do is create a separate entity that holds notifications that inform the user what they are supposed to do. eg.

"You were invited to match X - go to the match to accept the invite"

Whereas I know how to do that I have a drifferent problem.

I'd like to "highlight" the matches that require an action from the user when I'm listing them. What's the best way to do so? Given That the Matches are a seperate entity and notifications are as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working under a few assumptions, which I unfortunately can't clarify (some day, I'll be a real contributor!):

- `User` entity has a 1:M relationship with: `Notification`, `Games`
- `Game` entity 'Invite' fires off an event, which is subscribed to and adds a `Notification` for invited `User`

Based on that, I'd suggest one of:

1. If all notifications are generated due to action from an entity, have some sort of `NotificationTriggerInterface` with a `getId` method. Compare the `Game` id to that id.

   - May not be particularly robust if you want to refer to any entity unique properties. (ala: `notification->getTrigger()->getMyEntityUniqueProperty()`)
2. If not, you could consider an Interface & subclass approach for the `Notification`:

   - Define the `Notification` class as an interface and concrete/default class.
   - Add a 'type' property to the interface for sanity when looping in your Twig template instead of several `instanceof` checks.
   - Have a `GameNotification` class that extends the default. Add in a `Game` property there.
   - Create an instance of this notification whenever a `Game` is the originator of the notice.

There are other, less palatable options (abundant template logic), but hopefully one of those should serve well.

Comment: Your assumptions are correct that's exactly how my setup is. I think I'll run with the first option. Thanks for the suggestion, was searching for a viable Idea for a long time

Comment: @user2421156 Had a chance to try this out, yet? Once you've been able to verify, I'd appreciate if you could accept my answer!